# Resources recommendation - Latent heat of fusion of metals

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, material-science

I am looking for a book on which there are the values of latent heat of fusion of the metals in J/cm3. Could you suggest me any books? I prefer books on which there are tables of values.